# Swift extensions on structs make private initialization protection impossible

Tags: swift

In Swift you can prevent an object from being initialized directly by making the initializer private. You might want to do this with a Factory pattern.

But if you create an extension, you can provide a different initializer and it compiles. It doesn't matter if the extension is in the same file or not. This could have serious consequences if your factory method does some data validation, for example.

Am I missing something about private inits? This seems very bad. Can I prevent this?

```
struct Foo {

    let data: Int

    // factory method
    static func makeFoo(data: Int) -> Foo {
        return Foo(data: data)
    }

    // private init with data validation
    private init(data: Int) {
         guard data < 100 else {
            fatalError("Foo should only have values under 100")
         }
        self.data = data
    }
}

extension Foo {
    init(someData: Int) {
        // This bypasses the data validation and puts Foo into an invalid state.
        self.data = someData
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I'd say this is a bug.  Looks like you can get around it by either making `Foo` a class or adding a private field.

Comment: Yes a private backing field works, but only if it's in a different file. Definitely a bug there.

Comment: Half of your problem is a known resilience bug. Apple's Jordan Rose has a proposal to [enforce that cross-module struct initializers call another in-module struct initializer](https://github.com/jrose-apple/swift-evolution/blob/restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers/proposals/nnnn-restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers.md), which of course is impossible if the initializers are private.

Comment: As far as whether it's a bug that you can add initializers that bypass in-definition initializers using an extension *within your own module*, you're welcome to debate that on [swift-evolution](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/). I'm not sure that there will be consensus that it is "definitely a bug" or that it is "very bad".

Comment: (The [swift-evolution thread for this proposal is here](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171002/040261.html).)

Comment: The [proposal review](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171113/041301.html) is underway.

Comment: The proposal has been [accepted](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171127/041801.html). There'll be a warning in the next dot release of Swift and Swift 5 will outlaw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per zneak's comments above, this will be disallowed in Swift 5.